# TensorFlow convolution with variable length examples

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to design a convolutional neural network to be trained on preprocessed audio files. Because the audio files are of different lengths the training examples are of variable size in one dimension. I have gotten the network to work by zero-padding all the examples to the same length but I am worried that that will make the network less accurate. I am using a TensorFlow placeholder and tried setting its shape to [1, None, None] so that whatever the shape of each example is it should fit. But this is giving me an error when it gets the the convolution part:

```
    conv = tf.layers.conv1d(
        inputs = input,
        filters = 20,
        kernel_size = 5,
        name = "conv"
    )
```

Is giving the error:

```
ValueError: Shape of a new variable (conv/kernel) must be fully defined, but instead was (5, ?, 20).
```

So it seems that TensorFlow won't allow convolution with an unknown shape using placeholders. Is there a workaround for this to run each example independently without padding them to the same length?

Comment: Not 100% confident, but I'm pretty sure you need the input shape to be fully defined. When it's time to update the weights for the neural network, any library needs to take the gradient of each weight with respect to each dimension of the input. If the dimensionality of the input changes each time, I don't think you can compute this gradient.

Comment: Thanks, I've been wondering if it's just not doable, but I'm fairly new to all this stuff so I thought I should ask.

Comment: Yes, you need the length dimension to be the same for all examples in the batch. What you can do after the convolution is to mask every example past its actual length with something like 0, -inf or +inf.